# Variant of the Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP) where distances do not matter?

Tags: terminology

Suppose you have $4$ cities $1, 2, 3$ and $4$. You want to find all ways to go from $1$ to $4$ such as $1=4$, $1=2-2=4$, $1=3-3=4$, $1=3-3=2-2=4$ and $1=2-2=3-3=4$. Distances between cities do not matter. What is the name of this TSP variant where I need to only find the possible routes (not requiring to connect all vertices but need to connect starting-point and end-point)?

Comment: Since distances don't matter, you are simply listing all permutations of all subsets of the remaining $n-2$ vertices.  I'm not aware of a standard name for this: it might just lie in the neutral zone between "not long enough to require a name" and "not elegant enough to deserve one", so I'd go with Tomas's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the *set of paths between two vertices of a simple, unweighted graph*. This has little to do with the TSP and I don't think there is a name for it, any preciser than I stated it.

Some kind of *depth-first search* might solve this, you may want to look on [this question on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18603/finding-all-paths-on-undirected-graph), where the matter already has been discussed.

Comment: There must be more specific name to this, not just *"set of paths between two vertices of a simple, unweighted graph"*. If uncareful, it is pretty easy to create $n!$ algorithm where $n$ is the amount of vertices. I am trying to find out whether a specific programming language such as Matlab has something ready done for this kind of problems. Finding the precise mathematical name would help googling.

Comment: I disagree, that there _must_ be a name. There are names for interesting problems, not for all problems. In graph theory, usually it is important to check, _if_ there is a path or what the _shortest_ path is or what the path of _least weight_ is, maybe even the _number_ of distinct paths. Computing the whole set of paths does not seem so interesting, that it would get a name or be integrated in any software and certainly not in matlab.

Comment: Also, note, that there are exactly $\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}\frac{(n-2)!}{i!}$ many paths on a complete graph with $n$ vertices. So you are bound to have a "$n!$ algorithm" in the general case no matter how careful you are. Read the link to the Mathoverflow-question I posted for a discussion on the efficiency of such algorithms.

Comment: Yes that is correct but you probably meant $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!}$ amount of arrangements, [A000522](http://oeis.org/A000522). I clearly need to stop going through the paths in some point, thank you for repeating that! So the [$O((np+1)(m+n))$ algorithm](http://mathoverflow.net/a/18634/36875) does not traverse all paths?! I haven't yet understood it, it is faster because it cuts traversing in some point "stuck"?!

Comment: I did not read this discussion carefully, the poster claims, it does traverse all paths. However, this is not a contradiction to $\mathcal O(n!)$-time, since it involves the number if paths $p$, which is generally in the size of $\mathcal O(n!)$. So this algorithm is not better than $\mathcal O(n!)$ in general, but guaranteed to behave better on sparse graphs. Also, I think my sum is right, since start and end vertex are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

*I want to draw more attention to this finding...*

> *You want to find all ways to go from 1 to 4 such as 1=4, 1=2−2=4, 1=3−3=4, 1=3−3=2−2=4 and 1=2−2=3−3=4.*

There is an exact solution for it, check up the integer sequence [A000522](http://oeis.org/A000522) for the total number of arrangements of a set with $n$ elements.